# String from array not working when passed to JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The following works well:

```
var options = '<select><option value ="Unknown">Unknown</option><option value ="Yes">Yes</option><option value ="No">No</option><option value ="Both">Both</option></select>';
alert(options)
```

However, if that string is produced via a PHP foreach, the variable options is not recognized, hence I cannot use with JS. For example:

```
<?php foreach($pickListFields as $field_id => $options): ?>
    <?php 
        $options_array = explode("\n", $options); 
        $options_select = '<select>';
        foreach($options_array as $k => $option) {
            $options_select .= '<option value ="' . $option . '">' . $option . '</option>';
        }
        $options_select .= '</select>';
    ?>
    var options = '<?= $options_select ?>';
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above variable options produced, does not work, even though when I see the source code with Firefox I can see that var options is:

```
var options = '<select><option value ="Unknown">Unknown</option><option value ="Yes">Yes</option><option value ="No">No</option><option value ="Both">Both</option></select>';
```

Why then it cannot be used, if it is the same as the first example? I cannot alert that, or assign it to a field, but I can with the first example.

Comment: Are you sure that the source code given is *exactly* the same? I would also try removing the space before the equality sign.

Comment: It is, you can see it... I just copy pasted.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to use it? I take it you are doing this within a javascript block? Can we see the $options from $pickListFields?

Comment: You have the options, they are the ones that I put in the var options, Unknown, etc.

Comment: Is it possible there are JavaScript errors or warnings? This may halt processing of your script.

Answer (score 1):

You are using php tags inside php instead of javascript tags:

```
var options = '<?= $options_select ?>';
```

should be:

```
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">var options="' . $options_select . '";</script>';
```

Comment: Not sure if this works... It is also adding that text in my page.

Comment: OK I had to remove the <script> part, since I was already inside javascript. But it is still not working, the new variable options obtained cannot be used :(

Answer (score 0):

try maybe html encode all output options, there can be some special chars hidden somewhere